# How to use excel pivot table to process the groups of data with one share column and same sub fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have a table with the header like below:

```
|    |     Group1        |     Group2        |
|Date| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 |
```

I want to use the pivot table to process the data, like a three dimension data.
The dimensions are `<Date, Data Field(like A,B,C,D), Group>`. So that I can do the data analysis, like what's the `A` in `Date_1` across all the groups, and something like that, for example, one of the possible pivot table can be:

```
|    |  Group1 | Group 2 |
|Date|         |         |
|D1  |sum of A | sum of A|
|D2  | ....              |
```

But I have no idea how to setup the pivot table so that it can recognize those data correctly.
Any idea or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same column"? Can you give an example. The original data seems like a three dimension data, how can I normalise it to the "same column“？

Comment: I think i should understand your idea, but the things is, the data will be expanded a new row everyday. So it is not easy to make "group1" and "group2" into the same columns. Also, in fact, I cannot change the original sheet template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of illustration what I meant (may not be a complete solution to your issue). Assuming data such as in A1:I5, I was suggesting reformatting it to as in A8:F14, then pivoting as indicated in the upper PT (with Fields List as shown):

[image: SO388898305 example]

The lower PT is my interpretation of @David Andrei Ned's solution, though only for `A1`, `B1` and `C1` values (not cell references).

Reformatting as I suggest, where new data is added daily, may not be practical without automation.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I agree this is the most clean and simple solution comparing to some vba programming stuff until now, thanks for such detail sharing. I will mark it as accept answer if I cannot get better one within two days :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put Date in the Row label, Groups in Columns label, and according to your preference, Data Fields also in Columns Label, it should give you a table matching what you asked for

To have your data set up for this pivot to work, I suggest ordering the data as follows:

X axis - Z1(Y axis) - Z2(Y axis)

10 - G1 df1 - G1 df2 - G2 df1 - G2 df2

11 - G1 df1 - G1 df2 - G2 df1 - G2 df2

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer. May be I miss something. My question is how can I let the pivot table to understand my original data in the sheet. It seems you give the answer about how to setup to generate the final pivot table.

Comment: I am using excel 2016 mac version, i think i am using the power pivot. But pivot table in excel.

Comment: i would suggest, contrary to pnuts' advice, to have all the data presented in 2d by X as date, Y as data fields (for group1) and in the column to the right of the final data field column (of group1), add the data fields for group 2, and so on.

After you select all data an run a Pivot with these you should be able to order the data as desired